# Blank page after using SignalR 2.2.0 in ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, iis-express

We implemented SignalR 2.2.0 in our ASP.NET MVC application.

During the first debug our application (F5 in VS) everything works, but if you leave the application (Shift + F5 in VS) and you restart a debug (F5 in VS), nothing happens, blank page.

Here are SignalR logs (first debug):

```
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427 is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CloseSocket(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : Abort(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection 0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : End(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
```

Here are SignalR logs (second debug):

```
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427 is New.
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CloseSocket(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : Abort(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection 0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : End(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (0fbf0f3b-9b3a-4ea6-9cd6-a89c81c49427)
"A NEW LINE IN FILE" -> SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Dispose(). Closing all connections
```

**Info**
If we kill the "iisexpress.exe" process, we notice that the application works again.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening? I ask because we are having an issue where inconsistently someone is on a page and then every now and again, the page just goes blank with very minimal html in source.

Comment: Nope, actually we kill the "iisexpress.exe" in pre-build event.